# File Print Wizard in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, printing

I want to print the source code, Opened `File-> Print`.
In the print its printing the full file path on top. I want to print only the file name. How can I do this?
The Text line `$FILE$` is printing the file path on top of the paper. I tried `$NAME$`,`$FILENAME$`, etc,. but not working? Any hope?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print the file name with `$FILENAME$`, Check IntelliJ IDEA documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/print.html?search=print#d1508548e218).

`Text line` :- In this text box, specify the contents of the header or footer. If necessary, combine plain text with print keywords. By default, IntelliJ IDEA suggests to print the name of a file `$FILE$` in the header and the current page number `$PAGE$` of all pages `$TOTALPAGES$` in the footer.
The following print keywords are recognized:

`$FILE$` prints fully qualified file name.
`$PAGE$`
`$DATE$`
`$TIME$`
`$FILENAME$` prints file name without path.
`$TOTALPAGES$`